# .htaccess regular expression syntax

Tags: regex, .htaccess

sorry for my bad English.
I would exclude from my website every referral spam that contains the word "buttons" because I'm tired of all "social-buttons", "buttons-for-your-website", "my-brother-buttons" ecc. that I can see in my Google Analytics report.
I'm not into Regular Expression, but I thought of something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)(.*)(buttons|button)(.*)\.com [NC,OR]
```

Is it wrong?
Could this method exclude this kind of referral?
I didn't tested it: I don't know how to do.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will block visits with referrals matching `button`, no need for the extra `s`, regex includes that (`button.*`):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*button.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.goaway.com [R=301,L]
```

---

Learn more about [mod_rewrite syntax](http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php)

Comment: It doesn't work :/ 
I changed .htaccess with your rule and the webiste was inaccesible :/